# Какие типы данных могут быть получены из $_COOKIE и $_SERVER?

Tags: php

Только ли строки и NULL? Или что то ещё?

Comment: сериализовать можно что угодно.

Comment: @teran Т.е. из `$_COOKIE` и `$_SERVER` может быть получен любой тип данных в зависимости от настроек сервера?

Comment: у РНР слабая типизация. Изначально эти массивы строковые (проверьте вардампом). Если надо другие типы - используйте преобразователи типа [intval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Содержимое `$_COOKIE` берется из строкового представления заголовков запроса. Соответственно, конечными значениями могут быть только строки. Хоть эти строки можно объединить в массивы (как и в `$_GET` и `$_POST`), *значениями* в этих массивах всё равно будут только строки. Даже если вы передадите `null`, он выйдет строкой нулевой длины.

Содержимое `$_SERVER` определяется в том числе окружением сервера и внутренним состоянием PHP, потому значения могут быть не только строками. Например, значение, соответствующее ключу `REQUEST_TIME` - число.

*Ключи* во всех массивах, этих и любых других, [могут быть автоматически приведены к числам](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php) из строкового представления.

Comment: Доп. вопрос: где смотреть тип? Например меня интересует `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Answer (score 1):

> Содержимое $_COOKIE берется из строкового представления заголовков запроса. Соответственно, значениями могут быть только строки.

Чуть не верно, в `cookie`, как и в пост можно передовать и массивы к примеру

```
setcookie('array[]', 'test');
setcookie('array[]', 'test');
setcookie('array[]', 'test');
setcookie('array[]', 'test');
```

и когда вы сделаете `var_dump($_COOKIE['array'])` то вы получите результат:

```
array {
   [0] => test,
   [1] => test,
   [2] => test,
   [3] => test
}
```

т.е. массивы, строки, integer.

Comment: Массивы понятно, а integer и null в каких случаях?

Comment: @andreymal :-D да с null'ом лишка да, а вот integer, в виду приведения типов может быть передано но запишется как string

Answer (score 0):

Значение $_COOKIE это строка, поэтому в $_COOKIE можно хранить все, что можно сериализовать в строку. 
Главное чтобы места хватило - там его не очень много не боле 4кб.
Таким образом, все кроме ресурсов (resource) можно поместить и прочитать из $_COOKIE.
Это логический, целый, с плавающей запятой, строки, массивы и объекты.

Answer (score 0):

Все кукисы передаются через HTTP заголовок `Set-Cookie: <string>\n`, никакие другие типы передать в куках нельзя. Но можно представить что-то в виде строки (например через механизмы query_string, serialize, JSON наконец).

Родной функционал PHP автоматических преобразований не делает, в массив $_COOKIE записываются строки из заголовков HTTP. Максимум, что он может сделать - решить проблему с массивами.

Код микро-теста:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['flag']) && $_COOKIE['flag']) {
    print 'PHP '.PHP_VERSION.PHP_EOL;
    print PHP_EOL;

    var_dump($_COOKIE);
}

/* Ставим */
setcookie('flag', '(bool)true');
setcookie('float', '(float)1.2');
setcookie('integer', '(int)5');
setcookie('string', "Hello!");
setcookie('array[]', "1");
setcookie('array[]', "2");
setcookie('array[]', "3");
setcookie('array[]', "4");
setcookie('array1', 'array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)');
setcookie('array2', "array('key' => 'param', 'name' => 'value')");
setcookie('sub_array', "array('data' => 'length', 'array' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))");

?>
```

Результат на моей машинке:

```
PHP 5.3.3

array(14) {
  ["flag"]=>
  string(10) "(bool)true"
  ["float"]=>
  string(10) "(float)1.2"
  ["integer"]=>
  string(6) "(int)5"
  ["string"]=>
  string(6) "Hello!"
  ["array"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  ["array1"]=>
  string(20) "array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)"
  ["array2"]=>
  string(42) "array('key' => 'param', 'name' => 'value')"
  ["sub_array"]=>
  string(58) "array('data' => 'length', 'array' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))"
}
```

Можно еще экспериментировать конечно, взять другу версию, но мой вам совет - считайте кукисы всегда строками, и если вам нужно передавать сложные типы данных - используйте что-то вроде json_encode/json_decode.

Однако, массивы `$_COOKIE` и `$_SERVER` - это все же массивы, никто не мешает вам туда записать все что можно записать в массивы.

```
$_SERVER['HELLO_TIME_FOR_ME'] = array('minutes' => 5, 'seconds' => 0);
var_dump($_SERVER['HELLO_TIME_FOR_ME']);
```

Правда существовать оно будет только до конца работы вашего скрипта, поэтому смысла в этом мало. То же самое и с `$_COOKIE` - записать можно, но ничего никуда передаваться не будет, ни в каком виде.

Массив `$_SERVER` предоставлен нам оболочкой PHP и зависит целиком от нее. Там может содержаться все, что оболочка нам даст, и соответственно - любые типы данных, а не только строки.

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php
$_SERVER содержит еще два массива:

> 'argv'
> Массив агрументов, переданных скрипту. Когда скрипт запущен в командой строке, это дает C-подобный доступ к параметрам командной строки. Когда вызывается через метод GET, этот массив будет содержать строку запроса.
> 'argc'
> Содержит количество параметров, переданных скрипту (если запуск произведен в командной строке).

а если учесть содержимое статьи http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php, то во внешних переменных можно хранить любые типы данных:

> Определение типов переменных
>
> Поскольку PHP определяет и конвертирует типы переменных (в большинстве
> случаев) как надо, не всегда очевидно, какой тип имеет данная
> переменная в конкретный момент времени. PHP содержит несколько
> функций, позволяющих определить тип переменной, таких как: gettype(),
> is_array(), is_float(), is_int(), is_object() и is_string(). Смотрите
> также раздел Типы.

поэтому у вас в вопросе кот Шредингера, если вы спрашиваете в каком виде хранятся данные, от ответ будет в виде текста, если вы спрашиваете какие данные можно сохранить в глобальных переменных, да любые... либо вы замыслили взорвать мозг своим удивительным открытием...